# SQL Substring Case Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

I'm trying to solve the following question on SQLPAD.

> Write a query to return the number of actors whose first name starts with 'A', 'B', 'C', or others.
> The order of your results doesn't matter.
> You need to return 2 columns:
> The first column is the group of actors based on the first letter of their first_name, use the following: 'a_actors', 'b_actors', 'c_actors', 'other_actors' to represent their groups.
> Second column is the number of actors whose first name matches the pattern.

Table: actor

```
  col_name   | col_type
-------------+--------------------------
 actor_id    | integer
 first_name  | text
 last_name   | text
```

Sample results

```
actor_category | count
----------------+-------
 a_actors       |    13
 b_actors       |     8
```

So far I've tried this:

```
select  CONCAT(substring(lower(first_name), 2, 1), '_actors') as actor_category , count(*)
FROM actor
group by actor_category
```

Not sure how to check the others condition.

Comment: Linking the critical part of your question to an external site is not acceptable.  Please delete the link and then finish asking your question.

Comment: And provide a [MRE] i.e. provide sample data (as DDL+DML) your query, your desired results and your actual results.

Comment: Consider using a case expression on the first letter of the first name. Not sure why you are starting your substring from the second character of the first name? You do about using dbfiddle to test your query right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need this. The question actually says specific for a,b,c and others. You are not doing specific for a.b.c

```
with getFistChar AS
(
    select substring(LOWER(first_name), 1, 1) ac
    from actor
)
select CONCAT(ac, '_actors')actor_category, COUNT(1)count
from getFistChar
where ac in ('a', 'b', 'c')
Group By actor_category
UNION
select 'other_actors'actor_category, sum(1)
from getFistChar
where ac not in ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

Comment: It doesn't actually help people to do their homework for them.

Comment: Agreed Sir. But it is not about homework. It is about solving problem.

Comment: Same thing, it's an interview question, just giving the answer means the OP learns nothing.

Comment: You're also encouraging bad questions. As Tim comments above, questions need to be stand alone, not dependent on external links.

Answer (score 1):

One easy option is to use CASE statement and group the result

```
SELECT actors,COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN first_name LIKE 'A%' THEN 'a_actors' 
            WHEN first_name LIKE 'B%' THEN 'b_actors' 
            WHEN first_name LIKE 'C%' THEN 'c_actors' 
            ELSE 'other_actors' END AS actors
    FROM 
        actor
    )t 
GROUP BY t.actors
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try this:

```
select  CONCAT(substring(lower(first_name), 2, 1), '_actors')  , count(1)
FROM actor
group by CONCAT(substring(lower(first_name), 2, 1), '_actors')
```

Comment: Same comments apply that I made to the other answer.